# Maximise GPU usage on a headless Raspberry Pi

Tags: headless, gpu

I have a headless Raspberry Pi 2 model B and my goal is to maximise the **heat output** from the CPU/GPU IC.

I've successfully maxed the 4-core CPU by running 4 instances of:

`yes > /dev/null &`

Is there a CLI command that will do a similar job for maximising the GPU usage? I want something that will run until I choose to kill it from the CLI too.

Comment: I'd imagine that running an OpenGL benchmarking suite (or a particular test from such a suite in a repeat loop) would be quite stressful on the GPU, but I'm not sure if that would work in parallel with the way you are maxing out the CPU (i.e. you might need something that runs ONLY on the GPU). Have you looked into this?

Comment: No, and that's exactly what I'd like to learn about. I've exausted my googling skills and haven't found anything.

Comment: Have you looked at any of these? https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-gpu-benchmark/ . I haven't tried these on an rPi yet, but I did use the first two on ubuntu.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the purpose of this experiment? there are better  ways to toast marshmallows for smores.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm conducting an experiment along the lines of: http://www.wired.com/2015/03/stealing-data-computers-using-heat/

Comment: my application relies on 2 Pis airgapped but in the same 2-Pi case, which means data can be transmitted via heat variations. I already successfully proved it can be done using CPU throttling alone, but the variation in temperature registered by the neighbour Pi is small and error-prone. I'm trying to create a faster temperature rise in order to speed up the data transfer process.